# getting error ValidatorError: Path `id` is required. in mongo DB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am getting this error while saving my `document` on collection

**ValidatorError: Path `id` is required.**

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-tree-hd0fo

```
const BlogPost = new Schema({
  id: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  empid: String,
  date: Date
});

BlogPost.pre("save", function(next) {
  var blog = this;
  console.log();
  var data = `${blog.empid}-${blog.date}`;
  blog.id = crypto
    .createHash("md5")
    .update(data)
    .digest("hex");
  next();
});
```

getting the error when I am trying to save data.
a

```
pp.get("/saveData", async () => {
  try {
    var blog = new BlogPostModel({
      empid: "test123",
      date: "19-Jul-2019"
    });
    console.log("before save");
    let saveBlog = await blog.save(); //when fail its goes to catch
    console.log(saveBlog); //when success it print.
    console.log("saveBlog save");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [Validation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html) docs, it says:

> Validation is middleware. Mongoose registers validation as a `pre('save')` hook on every schema by default.

And in [Save/Validate Hooks](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#order), it says:

> The `save()` function triggers `validate()` hooks, because mongoose has a built-in `pre('save')` hook that calls `validate()`. This means that all `pre('validate')` and `post('validate')` hooks get called before any `pre('save')` hooks.

So it will validate before your `pre('save')` hook and give the error because you didn't provide the required field. You can solve it by changing `pre('save')` to `pre('validate')`.

Editted sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-lederberg-rth1k

Answer (score 0):

### when you are saving your blog documents you are not passing id field.

id is automatically generated by mongo, you don't need to specify it.
Remove id from BlogPost schema.
But if you want to give your own id then pass a unique id.

```
const BlogPost = new Schema({
  empid: String,
  date: Date
});
```